# How to set up a remote multiuser development environment with directory access permissions and git?

Tags: git, permissions, development-environment, agile

I'm developing a web app (AWS, PHP, complex front-end logic, multi-component, multi-module) leading a small distributed team (we use git) and preparing to introduce mode developers to the team. However we would like to isolate application modules and underlying code base among devs.
E.g.: we want front end devs to be exposed only to their part of the code.

It is important to remain within one dev instance and one app path, due to environment setup, one dev DB with sample data, etc.

Currently, the solution I see, is to set users and user groups with appropriate permissions, allow and disallow certain directories, etc. However it is not clear how to work with git in the context.
…maybe this approach is completely  irrelevant.

How should i go about this?

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for something that goes beyond the stock capabilities of `git`.  Have you looked at [Gitlab](http://gitlabhq.com/) or [Gitorious](http://gitorious.org/)?  These provide an interface similar to Github.  Gitlab seems to be geared more for development within an organization, where not everything is visible to others, but you may be able to achieve something similar with Gitorious.

Comment: Yeah, these are git repo hosting solutions. They still imply that the development is done under local dev environments with full repo clones. And I want to eliminate both: neither the developer should be running code on his local machine, nor he has to be exposed to the entire repo.

Or am I misunderstanding something about their advanced functionality?